# `xdg-open .` opens file manager, but opens Audacious with sudo permissions

Tags: xdg-open

`xdg-open .` opens file manager, but opens Audacious with root permissions. It then proceeds to play all system sounds! I'm just trying to open the file manager with `sudo`. Is there a better way to do it?

(On Lubuntu so I don't have nautilus or gnome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdg-open` is not always configured to open the correct application by default.  You can start Lubuntu's file manager directly by running `pcmanfm`.

Comment: And since Lubuntu 18.10 (with the switch to LXQt), it's `pcmanfm-qt`.